# Error in caculating simple linear regression of sanlinity index with one of selected bands

Tags: javascript, linear-regression

I am trying to calculate simple linear regression of SI with one of the selected bands (for example: B3, B4, NIR,...) and I get 3 errors:

```
List (Error)
Array: Parameter 'values' is required.
ComputedObject (Error)
Array: Parameter 'values' is required.
omputedObject (Error)
Array: Parameter 'values' is required.
```

[image]

```
var vietnam= ee.FeatureCollection("users/ngoc/gadm36_VNM_TINH");
 /*Map.addLayer(vietnam,{color:'pink'},'vietnam');*/


var TV = vietnam.filter(ee.Filter.eq('VARNAME_1', 'Tra Vinh'));
Map.addLayer(TV,{color:'green'}, 'polygon',1,0.8);
var border = ee.Image().byte().paint({featureCollection:TV, color: 1, 
width : 2})
Map.addLayer(border,{palette:'blue'},'ranh gioi tinh TV');


var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
 .filterDate('2017-12-01', '2018-04-30')
 
var filtered = S2.filter(ee.Filter.eq('CLOUD_COVER', 10));
var img=S2.mean().clip(TV);

var pallete = { bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], 
min: 6000, 
max: 10000
};
Map.centerObject(TV, 8);
Map.addLayer(img,pallete,'Sentinel 2');

print(filtered);


// Load the Cloud Score+ collection
var csPlus = ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/CLOUD_SCORE_PLUS/V1/S2_HARMONIZED');
var csPlusBands = csPlus.first().bandNames();

// We need to add Cloud Score + bands to each Sentinel-2
// image in the collection
// This is done using the linkCollection() function
var filteredS2WithCs = filtered.linkCollection(csPlus, csPlusBands);

// tinh toan SI1
 var SI1 = img.expression('((B3*B3)+(B4*B4))**0.5',{
      'B3': img.select('B3'),
      'B4': img.select('B4'),
  }).rename('SI');
  var vis= {
    min:-1,
    max:1,
    palette:['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
 '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
 '012E01', '011D01', '011301']
  }
Map.addLayer(SI1.clip(TV),vis,'Salinity Index');

var B3 =img.select('B3')

//linear regression


var B3 =img.select('B3')

var newBands = ee.Image([B3, SI1])

var image = newBands.select('B3') 
          .addBands(SI1).rename('B3','SI');

print(image)
// Chuyển/Gán giá trị pixel trên ảnh VT ứng với những điểm mẫu

var img_data = image.sampleRegions({
  collection:geometry,
  geometries:true
})
.map(function(feature){
  return feature.set('constant',1)
})

//có thể import điểm to drive

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection:img_data,// biến dữ liệu cần xuất
  description:'B3_SI1',// mô tả dữ liệu vector
  fileFormat:'SHP',//xuất dưới dạng shp
  fileNamePrefix:'B3_SI1_points',
  folder:'B3_SI1_points'
});


//ee.Reducer.linearRegression(numX, numY)

var linearRegression = ee.Dictionary(img_data.reduceColumns({
  reducer:ee.Reducer.linearRegression({
    numX:2,// constant và SI1
    numY:1,
  }),
  selectors:['constant','SI1','B3']
}));
print(linearRegression)

// lấy giá trị
var coef_List = ee.Array(linearRegression.get('coefficients')).toList()
print(coef_List)
// 
var slope =ee.List(coef_List.get(1)).get(0)
print('Giá trị độ dốc',slope)

var intercept =ee.List(coef_List.get(0)).get(0)
print('Giá trị Intercept',intercept)
```